# Visualise bonds in ASE

Tags: visualization-software, atomic-simulation-environment

I want to visualize an MD trajectory produced with ASE.

- ase.visualize.view produces an output for atoms and trajectories. I am not able to show the bonds between atoms.
- For atoms, I can use this in my jupyter notebook, which gives me an ok 3D representation:

```
from ase.visualize import view
view(atoms, viewer='x3d')
```

- For trajectories, I use this, which pops up a 2D representation and is very scarce (no bonds, no cell...):

```
read_traj = ase.io.trajectory.TrajectoryReader(traj_file)
view(read_traj)
```

- eventually, I would like to see them breaking later with a reaxff or MLIP such as MatGL.
- How do I show the cell and bonds? should I allow some flags to represent bonds? Or am I doing a totally wrong cell?
- Do automatic tools such as MDTraj or MDAnalysis have an interface to ASE?
- I know I can use VMD, but my local file is aliased at `/Applications/VMD\ 1.9.4a57-x86_64-Rev12.app/Contents/Resources/VMD.app/Contents/MacOS/VMD`
- I tried with the conda install of AVOGADRO but I get:

```
read_traj = ase.io.trajectory.TrajectoryReader(traj_file)
view(read_traj, viewer='Avogadro')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 2
      1 read_traj = ase.io.trajectory.TrajectoryReader(traj_file)
----> 2 view(read_traj, viewer='Avogadro')

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ase/visualize/__init__.py:10, in view(atoms, data, viewer, repeat, block)
      7     return
      9 vwr = viewers[viewer.lower()]
---> 10 handle = vwr.view(atoms, data=data, repeat=repeat)
     12 if block and hasattr(handle, 'wait'):
     13     status = handle.wait()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ase/visualize/external.py:72, in CLIViewer.view(self, atoms, data, repeat)
     66     atoms = atoms.repeat(repeat)
     68 proc = subprocess.Popen(
     69     [sys.executable, '-m', 'ase.visualize.external'],
     70     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
---> 72 pickle.dump((self, atoms, data), proc.stdin)
     73 proc.stdin.close()
     74 return proc

TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object

/Users/marcodigennaro/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py:127: RuntimeWarning: 'ase.visualize.external' found in sys.modules after import of package 'ase.visualize', but prior to execution of 'ase.visualize.external'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
```

Can anyone advise on any of the previous points?

Thank you

Marco

Comment: Bond visualization is tricky. This is because each program has its own way to do it. Did you try with other software like VMD, Jmol?

Comment: I tried with the conda installed vmd and avogadro. No chance. Is there a way to use my local installation of VMD with the proper location?

Answer (score 2):

- To visualize a trajectory in ASE, you have to use the default `'ase'` viewer. The `'x3d'` viewer currently only allows visualizing one structure.
- When you open the ase viewer GUI, you can simply press **Ctrl+B** to visualize bonds, and **Ctrl+U** to visualize unit cell. In command line, you can simply do `ase gui -b md.traj` to visualize bonds.
- If you want to make a movie that shows the change of the bonds, it becomes tricky. Although you can visualize bonds in ase GUI, when you save a snapshot as an image, the bonds disappear. Writing to a movie, e.g. `ase.io.write('movie.gif', read_traj)`, do not support showing bonds either. Maybe you can work around by taking a screenshot for each snapshot, but my suggestion would be to download the [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org) tool. You can find a code example [here](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/io/io.html#examples) for generating a high quality image of the C$_2$H$_4$ molecule with bonds using ASE and POV-Ray. You will need to generate an image for each snapshot, then combine them into a movie.
- To the best of my knowledge, neither MDTraj nor MDAnalysis have an interface to ASE. However, you can check out the list of structure file formats supported by ASE [here](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/io/io.html#file-input-and-output). Essentially, if you choose a format that can be read and written by both ASE and MDTraj/MDAnalysis, you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. Unfortunately, 'ase' or 'x3d' give exactly the same result, also from the command line. There is a warning message "setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array would exceed the maximum number of dimension of 1."

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro What do you mean "'ase' and 'x3d' give exactly the same result"? They are completely different viewers. Unless you provide your trajectory file, I cannot know why it isn't working for you. I have tested some trajectory files and it works as I stated.

Comment: I mean they both open a python 3.11 window (3 actually: graph, movie and trajectory)

Comment: <Popen: returncode: None args: ['/Users/marcodigennaro/miniconda3/envs/PGEL/...>

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro Yes they are supposed to open those 3 windows. So what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that I can see bonds neither from the command line (ase gui -b/u md.traj) nor with the shortcuts (Ctrl+B/U)

Comment: Hello, quick update:  the shortcuts Ctrl+B/U work fine. The problem was that the bond color is withe, so it was not visible -_-*